# What do we do with a group member who brazenly cheats?

Tags: problem-players, adnd-2e, cheating

One player is my group is starting to be a problem. He has started to do things like reading the module and other sources of spoilers to the campaign I'm running, and he frequently tries to solve a problem with "science". Most of the time it's not even real science!

We have tried to tell him that but he just pouts about how unfair we are being.

What do I do about this? He has always been in the group and we are good friends so I can't just kick him out.

Comment: [Here is a related question on dealing with players who cheat](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63124/how-do-you-tell-someone-you-think-they-are-cheating)

Comment: When you say he "tries to solve problems with science", what exactly do you mean? Does he claim the existence of bogus physical laws that would allow him to achieve otherwise impossible things? Does he just say "I'll use science" and then smash things? Does he try and create gunpowder in a setting that hasn't discovered it despite his character having the intelligence of a pidgeon and no knowledge of alchemy? If you clarify the nature of the behaviour we may be better able to help you deal with it.

Comment: Okay, having got my hands in the guts copyediting, these are the things I wanted to write more clearly but lacked the necessary information on: 1) What have you told him that makes him pout? (That it's not real science? That he's not allowed to cheat? What?) 2) What is this “science” he's trying to do and why is it causing a problem? (Is it that he's using scientific knowledge his PC wouldn't have? Is it something else? What?) Fix those two things and this *should* be clear enough to answer.

Comment: Answer in answers, not comments please.